# How do I configure Visual Studio for Mac to use iTerm2 rather than Terminal?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, console-application, iterm2

From what I can see, there is no option to choose which console Visual Studio for Mac should use when running Console Applications. Does anyone know a work around that can enable Visual Studio for Mac users to use iTerm2 instead of Terminal. Please note that I'm talking about Visual Studio for Mac, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You cannot currently change it (at least in an easy manner....it is hackable via a custom addin and reflection). `MacExternalConsoleProcess.cs` is hardwired to use `AppleScript` to control `Terminal.app` and there are some private property/methods that disallow writing in AddIn to override the default console behavior (same is true for MonoDevelop on Linux where it is hardwired to 4 term types). I issued a pull request a looooong time ago to MonoDevelop to allow a 3rd-party Addin to extend the MacPlatform interop and expose the console to allow it to be overridden but it never got accepted.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for the info. Do you have the URL?

Comment: @PerLundberg URL?

Comment: "I issued a pull request " -> the URL for the PR @SushiHangover